# Files doesn't copied into docker image

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

I'm building docker image with gitlab-CI with the next Dockerfile:

```
ARG BUILD_VERSION="prod"
FROM php:8.2.1-fpm as base
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libicu-dev libonig-dev libcurl3-dev libxml2-dev ssh git nano mc \
    &&docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mysqli mbstring curl intl xml \
    &&apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
COPY ["php/conf.d/error_reporting.ini", "/php/conf.d/timezone.ini", "/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/"]
FROM base AS version-prod
RUN composer update
FROM base AS version-dev
RUN pecl install xdebug && rm -rf /tmp/pear
    COPY ["php/conf.d/xdebug.ini" , "/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/"]
EXPOSE 22
FROM version-${BUILD_VERSION} AS current
# This select current version
FROM current
```

Corresponding gitlab-ci.yml is quite simple:

```
Build:
  stage: build
  image: docker:latest-git
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - docker info
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    - docker pull $CI_REGISTfRY_IMAGE:php-latest || true
    - docker build --cache-from $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:php-latest --tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:php-$CI_COMMIT_SHA --tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:php-latest -f ./Dockerfile .
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:php-latest
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:php-$CI_COMMIT_SHA
```

But when i deploy the container on this image, there is no files `php/conf.d/error_reporting.ini` and  `/php/conf.d/timezone.ini` in the container present.
Why is that happening?

Comment: You are copying your files to `/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/`, did you check in this directory?
There also might be a problem which causes the dockerfile to search for the file in `~/php/conf.d/timezone.ini` because its prefixed with`/`.

Comment: sorry, just typo... actual source path is usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/

Comment: still no files in the running container

# docker exec my-php bash -c "ls -la /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d"
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Jul 21 10:49 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Jul 11 01:01 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   96 Jul 11 01:01 docker-fpm.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   18 Jul 21 10:49 docker-php-ext-intl.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   20 Jul 21 10:46 docker-php-ext-mysqli.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   23 Jul 21 10:46 docker-php-ext-pdo_mysql.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   17 Jul 11 01:01 docker-php-ext-sodium.ini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the docker-compose.yml that built the project had the wrong image reference in the register
Thanks to all whatever!